# How to Pass This Test Case?

Tags: java

I'm creating the program that determines the largest and smallest number is a series of numbers entered by the user. I've created several tests cases for my code and they all work out, but it fails the most simple test case. When the user inputs a single number. For instance, if the user sets the terminating value to be 25, then enters -1, and finally enters the terminating the value, the output should be 
Largest: -1 and Smallest: -1. However, my code will output Largest: 0 and Smallest: -1 -- I why this happens (because I initialized the max value to be 0 before running the loop), but how can I fix this?

Here's my code...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declaration variables
    double min;
    double max = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter terminating number: ");
    double terminator = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    double num = scan.nextDouble();
    min = num;

    if (num == terminator) {
        System.out.println("There must be one number in the list.");
        // break;
    } else {
        while (num != terminator) {
            System.out.println("");
            num = scan.nextDouble();

            if ((num < min) && (num != terminator)) {
                double temp = min;
                min = num;
                max = temp;
            } else if ((num > min) && (num != terminator)) {
                max = num;
            } else {
                max = min;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
    }
```

Comment: `max` should be `Double.MIN_VALUE`... and `min = Double.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Initialise max to a very small number i.e. `Double.MIN_VALUE` and min to a very large number i.e. `Double.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @c650 I think you meant the exact opposite - max should be `Double.MIN_VALUE` and min should be `Double.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @D.B. thanks for catching that. I'm half-asleep.

Comment: Since the first input is handled specially, there's really no need to initialize `max` and `min` beforehand at all.  The variables don't even need to be declared until after `num` has first been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing `max = 0`, do `max = num` just like you already do with `min`.

It's not clear why you're initializing `max` differently from `min`; when a single number has been entered, it's both the minimum and the maximum.  Right now, the only code that modifies `max` is within the loop that reads numbers beyond the first, so the first number has no effect on it.

Comment: Okay this makes a ton of sense. Also, it doesn't affect other tests cases where the user enters multiple numbers. Thanks!

Comment: You have bugs affecting other number sequences, BTW: try 2, 1, 1 and 2, 1, 0, 1 as test cases.  And notice that your if/else logic assigns a new value to `max` in all cases, but never actually checks whether `num > max`.

Comment: I added in (num > max) in the else if statement.